# I have question about some command in linux

Tags: linux

I've learned linux and there's my homework:

1. Show all files and directories in /usr and save the result in file usr.txt:
2. Show all files in /usr/bin and stop when the screen is full:
   Hint: use command pipe and more
3. Find all files in /etc that the file name contains the word “log”:
   Hint: use command grep

1.I searched copy command on google but there's just some commands about copy file not contents and I also use Y1G command but there're nothing happen.

2.I absolutely don't have any idea about how to pharse "the screen is full" by commands

3.I've use command find path -log /etc but there're no right result

Comment: Sounds like homeworks :)

Comment: 1. `cd ~/usr` `ls > usr.txt`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. Show all files and directories in /usr and save the result in file usr.txt:

`cd /usr && ls -l > usr.txt`

> 2. Show all files in /usr/bin and stop when the screen is full:
>      Hint: use command pipe and more

`ls -l /usr/bin | more`

> 3. Find all files in /etc that the file name contains the word “log”:

`grep -ir "log*" /etc`